# Prevent page reload in create-react-app after image/file upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am getting images from folder inside 'src' folder (App is created with 'create-react-app').

- Node js server

  - ...
- client

  - src

    - /images
    - index.js
    - package.json
    - ...
  - public

I have form, which after submitting uploads a new image to folder **'client/src/images'**. After that page automatically reloads. I have database with user model and this model has image in string format. So after submitting a form a new image is created and pushed in **'/images'** folder which causes page reload. I need to prevent this. How can I disable react to watching this specific folder? Or as alternative I want to load images outside src directory. I found **react-app-rewired**, but I really didn't understood it.

I will be grateful for your answer/advice!

Comment: please add what and how you've implemented, please add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this , okkay so what you want to do is either remove submit type from button
`<input type="button" value="Basic file Upload">`
or call your imageUplaod function on onClick event instead of on submit .

it could be realted to web pack , you can ignore images folder :

```
module.exports = {   
devServer: {     
   watchOptions: {
      ignored: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),         
                 path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),         
                 path.resolve(__dirname, 'images') // image folder path 
                ]    
}},}
```

Comment: is your app configured with webpack , because webpack kinda listens to files changes and it reloads app on change

Comment: I said that App is created with create-react-app, so yes, webpack configs are somewhere in node-modules folder

Comment: can you check my update

Comment: Thank's for answer, but..) Yeah another 'but' xD My problem is in webpack-server that is watching for file changes. And when form is submitted, new file is loaded to folder, which is watched by server, so as consequence entire application is reloaded. I need to ignore this specific folder or store this folder outside '/client' directory, but as I wrote, create-react-app doesn't allow to import files outside of '/src' folder(

Comment: try this : 
```module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'images') // image folder path
      ]
    }
  },
}```

Comment: you might wanna configure webpack your self check my update

Comment: I found it yesterday, but the thing is that i don't know where i have to paste it. There are 7 webpack configs in node modules. I paste it on one of them, didn't work. I created webpack.config.js in directory(client), also didn't work. Or I need to install webpack in client directory?

Comment: yeah you need to install webpack and recon,fig your app from scratch ,check out traversy media's tutorial on react webpack